# Program that reminds me when my TV show airs

Tags: windows, gratis, reminders

Is there a program that will remind me when a TV show is going to air? Or at least will keep track of them and display them?

- Windows 7
- Runs from the desktop (not a web-app, ideally)
- Freeware preferably
- Should support most major US networks
- Ideally would know when a show is not playing for the week/month/whatever (i.e. doesn't just remind me weekly)

Comment: Country might be important here.

Comment: Added the country

Answer (score 1):

[**EpisodeCalendar**](http://episodecalendar.com/) (web app) can do that. It's free, supports shows for most major US networks, and shows schedules of when a TV show will air. It can email you the day your TV show will air (can also be set to email weekly). It can also be set to move all episode notifications a day forward, for users outside American timezones.

Screenshot of my subscribed TV shows calendar for this month (I'm also subscribed to other TV shows, like Game of Thrones, but since it is not airing this month, it is not shown):
[image]

Comment: This is super useful, but I'm really hoping for something that can run from my desktop.  If no one posts about that soon(ish) though I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

I was a long time user of EpisodeCalendar (see galacticninja's answer), but I have recently converted over to [RS TV Show Tracker](https://lab.rolisoft.net/tvshowtracker.html).

> RS TV Show Tracker is a software designed for TV show addicts – by a TV show addict.
>   The software allows you to keep track of all the TV shows you watch, by notifying you when a new episode was aired.
>
> Key features of the software:
>
> - Full Aero interface and support lots of Windows 7 features, like progress bar in the taskbar
> - Display summaries and screen captures of the episodes for a quick recap.
> - Automatically mark episodes as seen as you watch them in your video player!2
> - Search for torrents, Usenet and RapidShare links.
> - Search for subtitles in more than 30 languages and download them automatically near the video file.
> - Search for online videos on Hulu, BBC iPlayer, Netflix, iTunes and other services.
> - Search for downloaded episodes on your hard drive or network shares blazingly fast!3
> - Read aggregated news and episode reviews in your language about the shows you’re watching.
> - Hook it up to your XMLTV files and catch local airs of your TV shows.
> - Organize your downloaded TV show files with the built-in intelligent file renamer.
> - Create symbolic links to the downloaded files instead of renaming them, this way you can continue seeding them!4
> - Display fun statistics like the total time you’ve wasted watching TV shows.
> - Share what you’re watching with your friends through Twitter, Identi.ca or Facebook!
> - Recommends you TV shows based on what you’re watching right now!
> - Open source software! Fork it, fix it, tailor it to your own needs!

It runs on Windows 7 and 8 as a desktop program and it is open source. From what I have seen it supports all US networks. The program displays the upcoming shows but does not have any automated reminder function.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Craig! But instead of yopy-pasting the description from the website (no prob with that, as you made clear it's a "cite") – could you [edit] your post and include how it matches the OPs requirements? Win7 and free is stated implicitly. But: Is it a desktop app? Are most major US networks supported? What about the requested reminder? Thanks in advance!